# copy tables from one database to another on C#

Tags: c#

I wanna copy a table from on access database to another access database using c#
both database contain a table called "check"
I want to copy check table from database1(backup) to database2(CheckDatabase)
backup location is on my D:\backup.accdb and Checkdatabase is on my DataDirectory
this is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //backup database
            OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\backup.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
            con1.Open();
            //main database
            OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\CheckDatabase.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
            con2.Open();
            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO CheckDatabase.check SELECT * FROM backup.check";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con1); ;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("restore complete");
            con1.Close();
            con2.Close();
```

1.when I run it, I get this error
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\HamrahPlus V2\HamrahPlus\bin\Debug\backup.mdb'.'
I made a specifice connection for each database but its still want to connect to my program roote to execute my query.
2.btw I dont know if this query will work or not!

Comment: Are you LEADER.OF.HELL?  Only a user and Admin can read the user folder.

Comment: its the windows profile name (changed to Admin) and has admin privilege too and the address is for project directory

Comment: Code will run from exe file.  Inside VS you must right click VS shortcut and Select Run As Admin.

Comment: You have to solve one issue at a time,  First solve the error that file is not found.  The copy can be done using Bulk Copy.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/performing-bulk-copy-operations?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

To do a cross-database insert, you only want to connect to the destination database. Then, the `SELECT` portion of the `INSERT` query needs reference the source database file name (and potentially path) as part of the SQL.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var destDb = @"|DataDirectory|\CheckDatabase.accdb";
    var sourceDb = @"D:\backup.accdb";

    using var con = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={destDb};Persist Security Info=True");
    using var cmd = new OleDbCommand($"INSERT INTO CheckDatabase.check SELECT * FROM [;DATABASE='{sourceDb}'].[check]", con);

    con.Open();
    con.ExecuteNonQuery();
} // `using` directive ensures the connection is closed
```

Comment: Id change your code to c# code but its not working

Comment: string destDb = @"|DataDirectory|\CheckDatabase.accdb";
            string sourceDb = @"D:\backup.accdb";

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={destDb};Persist Security Info=True");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand($"INSERT INTO CheckDatabase.check SELECT * FROM [;DATABASE='{sourceDb}'].[check]", con);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: error is 'Not a valid file name.'

Comment: Then make sure the path is correct and the file really exists at that location.

Comment: yeah its there but not working. I think we need 2 connections

Comment: No, two connections cannot work.

Comment: need one connection to select from backup database and make a data table then make second connection to main database and insert into it